# Redux-form onChange Handler Possibly Overwritten

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I created a conditional field which displays yes and no radio buttons.  If Yes is selected then the child components should be shown.

The following code accomplishes that.  The issue is the selection of yes or no is not registered in the redux state.  If I remove the onChange function then the redux state is updated with the Yes or No value, but of course the child components won't show.

I believe the onChange function I pass is overwriting some other onChange function passed by redux-form.  Tried many things but had the same result.

I was thinking of just linking the value property with ReactLink, but it's deprecated.

Using React 0.15, Redux-Form 6.0 alpha, and ES7.

```
const YesNoRadioButtonGroup = (props) =>
  <RadioButtonGroup {...props}>
    <RadioButton value='Yes' label='Yes' className={s.radio}/>
    <RadioButton value='No' label='No' className={s.radio}/>
  </RadioButtonGroup>

// TODO: Clear child fields when "No" is selected
// TODO: See if we can generalize into ConditionalField
export class ConditionalRadio extends React.Component {

  state = {conditional: false}

  updateConditional(event) {
    console.log(event)
    this.setState({conditional: event.target.value === 'Yes'})
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <Field name={this.props.name}
             component={YesNoRadioButtonGroup}
             onChange={::this.updateConditional} />  // The trouble line.

      {this.state.conditional ? this.props.children : null}
    </div>
  }
}
```

It is used like this:

```
       <ConditionalRadio name='willRelocate'>
              <Field name='willRelocateTo.withinCurrentState' component={Checkbox} label='Within Current State'/>
              <Field name='willRelocateTo.outOfState' component={Checkbox} label='Out of State'/>
              <Field name='willRelocateTo.outOfCountry' component={Checkbox} label='Out of Country'/>
        </ConditionalRadio>
```

Comment: Thats very possible https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/4860e0c54a22cde68ffdea28d278f25158282dfd/src/readField.js#L118

Comment: @AvraamMavridis That was a fast find.  Would this be a bug?  Any idea where to look for a work around?

Comment: according to the docs/examples you dont need to maintain state internally in the component http://redux-form.com/5.2.5/#/examples/simple?_k=g779uz, is it a reason you need that? It should be doable to achieve what you want by "listening" on the store/passed params.

Comment: @AvraamMavridis Just keeping the state to determine whether to show child fields. (using version 6 btw, it is in alpha)

Answer (score 3):

If you have defined the field name when creating your redux-form, then you just have to call the default onChange event for that field inside your custom change event handler.

In your case that should be:

```
  updateConditional(event) {
    this.setState({conditional: event.target.value === 'Yes'});
    this.props.fields.name.onChange(event);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use the function componentWillReceiveProps in which you can check the new value then set the new conditional? see all helpful React lifecycle functions [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html)

Your Component would be written like this:

```
export class ConditionalRadio extends React.Component {

  state = {conditional: false}

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const displayChildren = nextProps.**value of the radio from redux form STORE** === 'Yes'
    this.setState({conditional: displayChildren});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Field name={this.props.name}
               component={YesNoRadioButtonGroup}/>
          {this.state.conditional ? this.props.children : null}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: What should this be `**value of the radio from redux form**`? Is it some info I didn't display here?  New to React so I need to do some work to grok when `componentWillReceiveProps` fires.

Comment: It's the property that his given to your component from redux-form? I guess if your component is connected to redux-form store, all fields value are mapped into your component... I didn't implement redux-form yet but I think it works like that.

Comment: I see what your saying.  But then shouldn't I be `connect()`ing to Redux?  Feels like it might be unnecessarily complex this way.

Comment: If you want to know the selected values from your radios without handle the onChange, it's the only way, isn't it?

Comment: You got all you want to fix your bug, go go go :)

Answer (score 0):

This works well:

```
class YesNoRadioButtonGroup extends React.Component {

  handleChange(event) {
    // Call the event supplied by redux-form.
    this.props.onChange(event)

    // If custom handler exists, call it.
    if (this.props.hasOwnProperty('customHandler')) {
      this.props.customHandler(event)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <RadioButtonGroup {...this.props} onChange={::this.handleChange}>
        <RadioButton value='Yes' label='Yes' className={s.radio}/>
        <RadioButton value='No' label='No' className={s.radio}/>
      </RadioButtonGroup>
  }
}
```